# Numpydoc style convention when returning an instance of a class

Tags: python, numpydoc

I'm following the `numpydoc` [style guide](https://developer.lsst.io/python/numpydoc.html#py-docstring-returns) to document my code but I cannot find the convention for returning an instance of a class :

```py
"""Create an index in the meilisearch API.  
If the argument \`uid\` isn't passed in, it will be generated by meilisearch.  
If the argument \`name\` isn't passed in, it will raise an error.  
Parameters  
----------  
name: str  
  Name of the index  
uid: str, optional  
  Unique identifier of the index  
Raises  
------  
HTTPError  
If no name is passed in as a parameter.  
HTTPError  
In case of any other error found here https://docs.meilisearch.com/references/#errors-status-code  
Returns  
-------  
index  
an instance of Index containing the information of the newly created index  
"""
```

In the returns section, as you can see, I return an instance of Index. 
Is this the way to document it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [numpydoc style guide](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#sections):

> **5. Returns**
>   Explanation of the returned values and their types. Similar to the **Parameters** section, except the name of each return value is optional. The type of each return value is always required.

```
Returns
-------
int
    Description of anonymous integer return value.
```

So for your example you would use `Index` as the type, together with an optional name:

```
Returns
-------
index : Index
    <some meaningful description here>
```

Here the `index :` part is optional.